# Transform array of array from all first elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm trying to convert to following array of array

```
[
  "master_type", # [0]
  [
    "type_1",    # [1][0]
    [
      "type_2",  # [1][1][0]
      [
        "type_3" # [1][1][1][0]
      ]
    ],
    [
      "type_3"   # [1][2][0]
    ]
  ],
  [
    "type_4",    # [2][0]
    [
      "type_2"   # [2][1][0]
    ]
  ],
  [
    "type_2",    # [3][0]
    "type_3"     # [3][1]
  ],
  "type_3"       # [3][1]
]
```

into something like

```
[
  ["master_type", "type_1", "type_2", "type_3"],
  ["master_type", "type_1", "type_3"],
  ["master_type", "type_4", "type_2"],
  ["master_type", "type_2", "type_3"],
  ["master_type", "type_3"]
]
```

Finally I would like to read this tree and collect all first elements when there are first elements then delete them before doing it again until my first array was empty.

How can I fix it?

It's important to note that this example is with strings but I'll do it with more complex objects.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: I didn't to anything that works just a bit. I just have in mind the algorithm but I can't solve it.

Comment: What's this `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, ...?

Comment: This is the way of **Awesome_print** to show array of array. It's to show the index

Comment: The Awesome_print output is not accepted commonly by everyone. Furthermore, if it is your style to write in Awesome_print format, then why isn't the expected output written in it? It is inconsistent. You will get less useful responses if you do not rewrite them to standard Ruby literals.

Comment: What are `master_type`, `type_1`, etc.? What are their values?

Comment: ^ I think he missed `master_type` and other strings to quote.

Comment: `master_type` is currently a string but at the end it will be an object. I wrote it like that to show that this is the main root. It is supposed to be on each arrays (see what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation is recursive, but I doubt it will overflow. If your trees are really deep, you may want to make it iterative instead.

```
def flatten_tree(tree)
  parent, *subtree = tree

  return [[parent]] if subtree.empty?

  subtree.flat_map do |element|
    flatten_tree(element).each { |children| children.unshift(parent) }
  end
end
```

*The answer was updated according to sawa's comments.*

Comment: Good answer. Although, since you are using `unshift`, you can change the `map` to `each`, which will be more efficient.

Comment: You can also omit the splat `*` before the `array`.

Comment: This is exactly what I expected. Thank you ! For me it's perfect because my trees are not that deep. It's perfectly working.